# Setup Cloudflare with Openshift and my actual registrar

Tags: dns, subdomain, openshift, cloudflare

My domain was bought from registro.br but it won't allow me to create CNAME entries without a subdomain, such as www. And Openshift seems to allow only CNAME entries.

So when I go to www.mysite.com it works well. But mysite.com won't work.

I heard some people talking about Cloudflare.

How can I make this system to work altogether? Is it possible?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

My advice is a full-host CloudFlare set up. Set it up via the nameserver route, not a Partner/Business/Enterprise CNAME record; this will also speed up your DNS performance.

Point your nameservers to CloudFlare after set-up, then in CloudFlare DNS point the CName record to Openshift.